# Python Reading and using data from file

Tags: python

I am currently trying to save scores from a quiz to an excel sheet which allows the user to read the files, but how can I use their save data to only save the last 3 scores of a user. I understand this would mean reading from the file to see the scores and then making it read how many tries the user has had etc. but I can't quite figure out how to make it so the program will only save the last 3 scores from that user or their 3 highest scores. Thank you.

```
            if pclass == 1:
                inFile = open("ascores.csv", 'a')
                inFile.write("\n" + pname + ", " + str(correct) + ", " + str(round(etime, 1)))
                inFile.close()
                inFile = open("ascores.csv", 'r')
                print(inFile.read())
            elif pclass == 2:
                inFile = open("bscores.csv", 'a')
                inFile.write("\n" + pname + ", " + str(correct) + ", " + str(round(etime, 1)))
                inFile.close()
                inFile = open("bscores.csv", 'r')
                print(inFile.read())
            elif pclass == 3:
                inFile = open("cscores.csv", 'a')
                inFile.write("\n" + pname + ", " + str(correct) + ", " + str(round(etime, 1)))
                inFile.close()
                inFile = open("cscores.csv", 'r')
                print(inFile.read(sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[0]))))
            else:
                print("Sorry we can not save your data as the class you entered is 1, 2 or 3.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the file before reading its contents.

```
if pclass == 1:
    inFile = open("ascores.csv", 'a')
    inFile.write("\n" + pname + ", " + str(correct) + ", " + str(round(etime, 1)))
    content = inFile.read()
    inFile.close()
    inFile = open("ascores.csv", 'r')
    print(content)
```

or more concise:

```
if pclass == 1:
    new_score = "\n" + pname + ", " + str(correct) + ", " + str(round(etime, 1))
    with open("ascores.csv", 'a') as in_file:
        in_file.write(new_score)
        content = in_file.read()
    print(content)
```

Using the `with` statement will close the file for you.
You can edit the long `new_score = "\n" + pname + ", " + str(correct) + ", " + str(round(etime, 1))` to:

```
new_score = "\n {}, {}, {:.1f}".format(pname, correct, etime)
```

see: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language for an explanation about string formatting.

You could also simplify your code (never repeat yourself):

```
def saveScore(pname, correct, etime, pclass):
    score_files = {1:"ascores.csv", 2:"bscores.csv", 3:"cscores.csv"}
    try:
        filename = score_files[pclass]
        new_score = "\n {}, {}, {:.1f}".format(pname, correct, etime)
        with open(filename, 'a') as in_file:
            in_file.write(new_score)
            content = in_file.read()         
        return content
    except KeyError:
        return None

print(saveScore(pname, correct, etime, pclass))
```

Comment: Thank you, I am just testing that out now to see if it works the same. But then how would i use this to only allow the user 3 scores saved to file? I need to make it so in the file, it will only save the 3 best scores of each user determined by the score and time they got. (best score and if they got 2 of same score, then it is determined by time). Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what you are doing now is appending the last score to the file. It doesn't check for a username in the file. What I understand is that you A: want to check whether a player_name already exists in the file and B: if A, then append write the new results to the player_name's line or C: if not A, then add a new line with the players scores? Right?

Comment: btw why are you using 3 files instead of 1? like:
`p_name, highscore, highscore_time, second_highest_score, second_highest_score_time, third_highest_score, third_highest_score_time`